# string representation of a numpy array with commas separating its elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, for example:

```
points = np.array([[-468.927,  -11.299,   76.271, -536.723],
                   [-429.379, -694.915, -214.689,  745.763],
                   [   0.,       0.,       0.,       0.   ]])
```

if I print it or turn it into a string with str() I get:

```
print w_points
[[-468.927  -11.299   76.271 -536.723]
 [-429.379 -694.915 -214.689  745.763]
 [   0.       0.       0.       0.   ]]
```

I need to turn it into a string that prints with separating commas while keeping the 2D array structure, that is:

```
[[-468.927,  -11.299,   76.271, -536.723],
 [-429.379, -694.915, -214.689,  745.763],
 [   0.,       0.,       0.,       0.   ]]
```

Does anybody know an easy way of turning a numpy array to that form of string?

I know that .tolist() adds the commas but the result loses the 2D structure.

Comment: numpy.set_printoptions really should have an option for this

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try using `repr`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = np.array([[-468.927,  -11.299,   76.271, -536.723],
...                    [-429.379, -694.915, -214.689,  745.763],
...                    [   0.,       0.,       0.,       0.   ]])
>>> print(repr(points))
array([[-468.927,  -11.299,   76.271, -536.723],
       [-429.379, -694.915, -214.689,  745.763],
       [   0.   ,    0.   ,    0.   ,    0.   ]])
```

If you plan on using large numpy arrays, set `np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)` first.  Without it, the array representation will be truncated after about 1000 entries (by default).

```
>>> arr = np.arange(1001)
>>> print(repr(arr))
array([   0,    1,    2, ...,  998,  999, 1000])
```

Of course, if you have arrays that large, this starts to become less useful and you should probably analyze the data some way other than just looking at it and there are [better ways](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) of persisting a numpy array than saving it's `repr` to a file...

Answer (score 51):

Now, in numpy 1.11, there is [`numpy.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html):

```
In [279]: a = np.reshape(np.arange(25, dtype='int8'), (5, 5))

In [280]: print(np.array2string(a, separator=', '))
[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Comparing with `repr` from @mgilson (shows "array()" and `dtype`):

```
In [281]: print(repr(a))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]], dtype=int8)
```

---

P.S. Still need `np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)` for large array.

Comment: You can also pass "threshold=np.nan" to the numpy.array2string function.

Answer (score 5):

The function you are looking for is `np.set_string_function`. [source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_string_function.html#numpy.set_string_function)

What this function does is let you override the default `__str__` or `__repr__` functions for the numpy objects. If you set the `repr` flag to True, the `__repr__` function will be overriden with your custom function. Likewise, if you set `repr=False`, the `__str__` function will be overriden. Since `print` calls the `__str__` function of the object, we need to set `repr=False`.

For example:

```py
np.set_string_function(lambda x: repr(x), repr=False)
x = np.arange(5)
print(x)
```

will print the output

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

A more aesthetically pleasing version is

```py
np.set_string_function(lambda x: repr(x).replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('array', '').replace("       ", ' ') , repr=False)

print(np.eye(3))
```

which gives

```
[[1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 0., 1.]]
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it, which is particularly helpful when an object doesn't have a __repr__() method, is to employ Python's pprint module (which has various formatting options). Here is what that looks like, by example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pprint
>>>
>>> A = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.int64)
>>>
>>> print(A)
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>>>
>>> pprint.pprint(A)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by simply doing this:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(label_list, dtype=np.int64)
```