# python numpy scipy griddata is nan or all the same value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot a contour with unevenly spaced data in python using numpy, matplotlib plyplot and scipy.

Given the following code snippet, why is zi either empty or all the same value?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

lon_min = 1.8783669
lon_max = 1.8792678
lat_min = 57.45827
lat_max = 57.459293

x = [ 520.99012099,652.23665224,800.,0.,520.99012099
  652.23665224,800.,0.,520.99012099,652.23665224 ...]

y = [   0.,379.47214076,437.53665689,600.,0.
  379.47214076,437.53665689,600.,0.,379.47214076 ...]

z = [ 56.6,56.6,56.6,56.6,45.3,45.3,45.3,45.3,57.8,57.8 ...]

xi = np.linspace(lon_min,lon_max,10)
yi = np.linspace(lat_min,lat_max,10)
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='nearest')

plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k') # this is blank or all the same colour because zi is either nan or all the same number depending on the method I use.
```

Applying a bit of debug it looks like zi is either NAN if I use method=cubic/linear or all the same number if I use method=nearest

```
print xi
print yi
print zi
```

gives:
    xi = [ 1.8783669  1.878376   1.8783851  1.8783942  1.8784033  1.8784124
      1.8784215  1.8784306  1.8784397  1.8784488  1.8784579  1.878467
      1.8784761  1.8784852  1.8784943  1.8785034  1.8785125 .... ]

```
yi = [57.45827     57.45828033  57.45829067  57.458301    57.45831133
  57.45832167  57.458332    57.45834233  57.45835267  57.458363
  57.45837333  57.45838367  57.458394    57.45840433  57.45841467
  57.458425    57.45843533  57.45844567  57.458456    57.45846633 .... ]

zi = [[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 ...,
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]

zi = [[ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 ...,
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]]
```

Comment: Can you turn this into actual Python code? It's incredibly annoying to deal with almost-code that's not runnable. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423774/string-representation-of-a-numpy-array-with-commas-separating-its-elements) for some help with outputting the arrays properly. People will be much more likely to answer the question this way.

Comment: The griddata call is also invalid for `scipy.interpolate.griddata`

Comment: From the documentation it doesnt seem as though you are passing griddata the proper values
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

griddata(points, values, xi, method='linear', fill_value=nan)

you are passing 5 values to griddata, do you know which values you think you are passing

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, I think the old scipy griddata takes 5 parameters whereas the newer one takes only 3? I'm using scipy 0.5

Comment: UPDATE: After updating scipy and numpy to newer versions I now get either all the same values (if I use method=nearest) or nan if I use method=cubic/linear - any idea why?  print zi (nearest)  [[ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 ...,
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]
 [ 46.7  46.7  46.7 ...,  46.7  46.7  46.7]]    print zi (cubic)    [[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 ...,
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]

Comment: @SamMaj Did this ever get resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to contour directly your data with tricontour ?

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tricontour#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour

```
plt.tricontour(x, y, z)
```

or if you need to see the underlying mesh:

```
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
triang = mtri.Triangulation(x, y)
plt.tricontour(triang, z)
plt.triplot(triang)
```

In your case, the triangulation is in fact reduced to 3 triangles, because you have duplicate points and consequently one unique z value at most has to be chosen for identical location. You can see better what happens using `tricontourf`, for filled contours. The duplicate points explain also why an interpolation routine might have troubles with this dataset...

Now if you randomly select 1 arbitrary z value for each of your 4 data points you could do

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

x = np.array([520.99012099, 652.23665224, 800., 0.])
y = np.array([0., 379.47214076, 437.53665689, 600.])
z = np.array([45.3, 57.8, 57.8, 57.8])

triang = mtri.Triangulation(x, y)
refiner = mtri.UniformTriRefiner(triang)
refi_triang, refi_z = refiner.refine_field(z, subdiv=4)

levels = np.linspace(45, 61, 33)

CS_colors = plt.tricontourf(refi_triang, refi_z, levels=levels)
plt.triplot(triang, color="white")
plt.colorbar()

CS_lines = plt.tricontour(refi_triang, refi_z, levels=levels, colors=['black'])
plt.clabel(CS_lines, CS_lines.levels, inline=True, fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: if i just do plt.tricontour(x,y,z) I get a blank image, the underlying mesh appears as a triangle: http://postimg.org/image/xczqqcpcf/

Comment: Thanks GBy I get that as well after following your code example, if I then modify my data to have unique x,y coordinates then I get this http://postimg.org/image/6o2hne2fn/ which looks better I think (although I don't actually know what it should look like!) if I then try to create a contour using    plt.tricontour(x, y, z) I get this http://postimg.org/image/ti01adgib/0233c1ac/ how do I now actually get a contour?

Comment: Happy if it helped. I am not sure what you mean exactly by "a contour" as for me your 2nd image **is** a contour ? Also, it would help to give your updated data.

Comment: Oh maybe my terminology is incorrect, this is what I thought a contour was and is what I am trying to achieve: http://www.idlcoyote.com/cg_tips/outcontourbar.png With regards to the data I just manually chose a set of random unique points from my data to see if the uniqueness was the issue and it looks like it was the thing that was stopping the system from graphing, but I'm not sure what I would use to create a graph similar to the link I have provided?

Comment: OK I see. It's easy, you just have to combine `tricontour`, `tricontourf` and `clabel`. See update.

Comment: Thanks GBy how do you fill the whole screen rather than have a triangle i.e. using contourf?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the entries in your grid are **NaN**. To verify that, run this code

```
nan = 0
notnan = 0
for index,x in np.ndenumerate(zi):
    if not np.isnan(x):
        notnan+=1
    else:
        nan+=1

print 'nan ', nan
print 'not nan', notnan
print 'sum ', nan+notnan
print 'shape ', zi.shape
```

You can plot zi using the command:

```
plt.imshow(zi)
```