# Delimiter error from np.loadtxt Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to sum some values in a list so i loaded the .dat file that contains the values, but the only way Python makes the sum of the data is by separate it with ','. Now, this is what I get.

```
    altura = np.loadtxt("bio.dat",delimiter=',',usecols=(5,),dtype='float')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 846, in loadtxt
    vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code

```
import numpy as np

altura = np.loadtxt("bio.dat",delimiter=',',usecols=(5,),dtype='str')
print altura
```

And this is the file 'bio.dat'

```
1 Katherine Oquendo M 18    1.50    50  
2 Pablo Restrepo    H 20    1.83    79  
3 Ana Agudelo   M 18    1.58    45  
4 Kevin Vargas  H 20    1.74    80  
5 Pablo madrid  H 20    1.70    55
```

What I intend to do is

```
x=sum(altura)
```

What should i do with the 'separate'?

Comment: Your file *isn't* comma-separated, what are you expecting `numpy` to do?!

Comment: Exacltly! it isn't comma-separated, i want it to be comma-separa

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Do you want to change the file? You have to tell `loadtxt` what delimiter is actually being used, once the data is imported from the file it will be in an array, which you can certainly `sum`. Could you please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the errors you see.

Comment: This is what i have using 
   altura = np.loadtxt("bio.dat",delimiter=',',usecols=(5,),dtype='str')  ->  ([ 1.5   1.83  1.58  1.74  1.7 ])

But i need this     ([ 1.5 ,  1.83,  1.58,  1.74,  1.7 ])   (with comma-separated)

Comment: No, you don't; that is just how the array is shown. The real question is: why on earth are you using `dtype=str` when you want numbers?!

Comment: Sorry, i copied wrong that part, is 'float'. If I dont use the comma-separated the sum is 0. 
I simulated the list with Ipython with and without comma-separated and it gave me the right answer with the comma-separated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16423774/3001761

Answer (score 1):

In my case, some line includes `#` character.
Then numpy will ignore all the rests of the line, because that means ‘comment’. 
So try again with `comments` parameter like

```
altura = np.loadtxt("bio.dat",delimiter=',',usecols=(5,),dtype=‘str’,comments=‘')
```

And I recommend you not to use `np.loadtxt`. Because it’s incredibly slow if you must process a large(>1M lines) file.

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't need to be comma separated.  Here's my sample run, using `StringIO` to simulate a file.  I assume you want to sum the numbers that look a person's height (in meters).

```
In [17]: from StringIO import StringIO
In [18]: s="""\
1 Katherine Oquendo M 18    1.50    50  
2 Pablo Restrepo    H 20    1.83    79  
3 Ana Agudelo   M 18    1.58    45  
4 Kevin Vargas  H 20    1.74    80  
5 Pablo madrid  H 20    1.70    55  
"""
In [19]: S=StringIO(s)
In [20]: data=np.loadtxt(S,dtype=float,usecols=(5,))
In [21]: data
Out[21]: array([ 1.5 ,  1.83,  1.58,  1.74,  1.7 ])
In [22]: np.sum(data)
Out[22]: 8.3499999999999996
```

---

as script (with the data in a .txt file)

```
import numpy as np
fname = 'stack25828405.txt'
data=np.loadtxt(fname,dtype=float,usecols=(5,))
print data
print np.sum(data)

2119:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack25828405.py
[ 1.5   1.83  1.58  1.74  1.7 ]
8.35
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Look, the reason why i'm trying to separate each value with comma is because of this

   Values for 'altura': [ 1.5   1.83  1.58  1.74  1.7   1.62  1.74  1.7   1.81  1.82  1.7   1.78
  1.7   1.78  1.74  1.66  1.64  1.76  1.7   1.67  1.68  1.8   1.74  1.92
  1.66]
   Sum of the values: 0

As you can see the terms are only separated with blanks, If I put the commas then the sum will give the result i need

Comment: But I get `array([ 1.5 ,  1.83,  1.58,  1.74,  1.7 ])` from your sample.  Are you using `np.sum`?  What is `altura`?  Is it a numpy array of floats?

Comment: Yes, i am. But what i'm doing to run it is 'python datosbiometricos.py' and there is when i get the error
Are you using Ipython to run it?
And yes, altura is an array of floats

Comment: I added a script run. That numbers are the same. Display is different, but that's not significant.  I wonder if your sum is 0 because `altura` is empty.  What is `altura.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can convert the tab delimited file to csv first.

`csv` supports tab delimited files. Supply the [`delimiter` argument to `reader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv

txt_file = r"mytxt.txt"
csv_file = r"mycsv.csv"

# use 'with' if the program isn't going to immediately terminate
# so you don't leave files open
# the 'b' is necessary on Windows
# it prevents \x1a, Ctrl-z, from ending the stream prematurely
# and also stops Python converting to / from different line terminators
# On other platforms, it has no effect
in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

This answer is not my work; it is the work of agf found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10220428/3767980.