# add a comma between the elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which looks like

```
a = ['blue' 'red' 'green']
```

and I want it to become

```
b = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

I tried

```
b = a.split(' ')
```

but it returns an error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: There's no numpy array in the snippet of code you've posted.

Comment: This is just a display issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string representation of a numpy array with commas separating its elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423774/string-representation-of-a-numpy-array-with-commas-separating-its-elements)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply turn it to a list:

```
a = numpy.array(['blue', 'red', 'green'])
print a
>> ['blue' 'red' 'green']
b = list(a)
print b
>> ['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

But why would you have a numpy array with strings?

Comment: record arrays, recarrays, structured arrays... are a very common useage of numpy arrays.  Numpy doesn't limit its dtype to one common type.  There is extensive documentation in the Numpy and SciPy documentation websites.  The only requirement is that each column/field is characterized by one dtype

Answer (score 8):

You can simply call tolist:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['blue', 'red', 'green'])

b = a.tolist()
print(b)
['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a list without commas and with arbitrary number of spaces. E.g.:

```
[2650   20    5]
[2670    5]
[1357  963  355]
```

I solved it this way:

```
np.array(re.split("\s+", my_list.replace('[','').replace(']','')), dtype=int)
```

From the console:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import re
>>> my_list = '[2650   20    5]'
>>> result = np.array(re.split("\s+", my_list.replace('[','').replace(']','')), dtype=int)
>>> result
array([2650,   20,    5])
>>>
```