# Python: How to turn whitespace separated input into a comma separated Array?

Tags: python, input

input

```
5 1 4 6 2 0 5 4 4 5 4
```

my code

```
import numpy as np
ARR = np.asarray( list(map(int, input().strip().split())) )
print(ARR)
```

output got

```
[5 1 4 6 2 0 5 4 4 5 4]
```

output expected

```
[5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 0, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4]
```

In particular, I either want to make a separated list, then convert to Numpy array, or do it all in one command line

Comment: When you print a numpy array, commas are omitted for readability. To get a string representation you want, you could simply use `print(list(map(int, input().strip().split())))` or `print(ARR.tolist())`.

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423774/string-representation-of-a-numpy-array-with-commas-separating-its-elements). I agree with the comment on the question that `numpy.set_printoptions` should support this.

Comment: thank you for linking that question, as i have found an answer through it, which is `print(repr(ARR))`

Comment: Glad it helped. In this case, you should close the question as as duplicate.

Comment: since this is my first time ever on this site, I don't know how to close it

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension

```
import numpy as np
res = np.array([int(x) for x in input().split()])
print(res)
```

Comment: This prints the same output OP gets in his example (without commas).

Answer (score 0):

Ans was very simple split on spaces like split(' ')

```
ARR = np.asarray( list(map(int, input().strip().split(' '))))
```

Output

```
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5])
```

Comment: in print, this also gives the same result, which in non comma seperated